# Can we get the JourneyActivityID by AMP Script?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, journeybuilder

I hope this message finds you well.

I currently have granularity data for email, SMS, and WhatsApp channels, but I've encountered a challenge with the Push channel's DataExtract. It's not providing the JourneyActivityID as needed.

As a potential solution, I'm considering inserting the JourneyActivityID into a SendLog. Could anyone advise if it's possible to retrieve the JourneyActivityID at send time and insert it into the SendLog by AMPScript? If so, could you please guide me on the process?

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Thank you!